# How do you force a UINavigationController to load its root?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following in myNavigationController.m:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    [self.view.layer addGradient];

}
```

I have a rootViewController created in my appDelegate but am getting issues sometimes that after being in my app for 2 days and logging out, the root view controller doesn't load.

So the above code ends up loading a blank view with my gradient and not my rootview controller.

The controller I want to load is called: myViewController.

How do I make that happen here?

Comment: You should be able to use `[self setViewControllers:@[myViewController] animated:YES]` though if I were you I would try first to get to the bottom of why the existing rootViewController is failing to load.

Comment: please paste the app delegate code

Comment: How would you do [self setViewControllers:@[myViewController] animated:YES] in the myNavigtionController when myViewController is declared in appDelegate?

Comment: @chris I have just found your other question; I think better to resolve that first, and come back to this question if necessary.  I'll add some suggestions to that other question.